# Address bar missing from Internet Explorer and not an option in tools

Tags: internet-explorer, address-bar

I clicked a link in Internet Explorer that opened in a new window.  This window does not have an address bar and when I go to add it back from the tools drop-down menu is it not an option.  Any other window opened in IE still has an address bar present, it only happens when I click on this specific link.  Is this just a setting of that website?  If I have permission to change the website what settings need to be changed in order to allow the address bar to show?

Comment: Or you could just post the link to the website, unless it is a bank or something, so someone could actually examine the webpage to give you a definite answer.

Answer (score 1):

It could've been done by Java Script. In the website source, look for something like:

```
window.open(...,  location=no, ...);
```

That `location=no` tels the browser to open the new window without address bar. Removing that `location=no` should make the new window to have the address bar. But be careful when modifying the code so that you don't remove unnecessary things. First make backup of whatever files you modify.

It could've been done in other ways though.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  I checked the source but didn't find any "window.open" or "location=no"

Comment: Yes, there are other ways to do this, but that's the one that I've used and know. Perhaps someone with more webdesign experience could say what else it could be.

Comment: Just because it isn't visible in the source doesn't mean a script loaded doesn't have it.

Comment: Rob: you are right. @Jen -- you could look at the source, check what scripts are loaded (these are usually at the top) and check the scripts themselves. The issue is that some of the script URLs may not be immediately obvious as they may have relative addresses, i.e. ../../scripts/script1.js and figuring out the exact URLs for the scripts may be slightly tricky.